# How to (zerop #*000) in common lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

Is there an efficient way to check if a bitvector is all zeroes? (I'm using SBCL on Linux.) I've looked through the documentation but could not find a suitable function. The best I've come up with so far is:

```lisp
(defun bit-zerop (array)
  (equal array (make-array (length array) :element-type 'bit)))

(bit-zerop #*000)
```

I've also tried

```lisp
(defun bit-zerop (array)
  (dotimes (i (length array))
    (if (eql (sbit array i) 1)
        (return-from bit-zerop nil)))
  t)
```

but it is about 100 times slower on larger bit vectors than the first version. (Which is expected, as each 64bit word is read 64 times, I guess, instead of just once). Of course, the first version is sub-optimal as well as it must allocate a new array.

**EDIT:** timings for mentioned solutions.

**EDIT 2:** timings with type declarations.

```lisp
(defun bit-zerop-1 (array)
  ;; (declare (simple-bit-vector array))
  (equal array (make-array (length array) :element-type 'bit)))

(defun bit-zerop-2 (array)
  ;; (declare (simple-bit-vector array))
  (every #'zerop array))

(defun bit-zerop-3 (array)
  ;; (declare (simple-bit-vector array))
  (loop
     for bit across array
     never (= bit 1)))

(defun bit-zerop-4 (array)
  ;; (declare (simple-bit-vector array))
  (not (find 1 array)))

(dolist (func '(bit-zerop-1 bit-zerop-2 bit-zerop-3 bit-zerop-4))
  (dolist (size '(10 100 1000))
    (let ((x (make-array size :element-type 'bit)))
      (format t "Testing ~a on ~a elements~%" func size)
      (time
       (dotimes (i 1000000)
         (funcall func x))))))
```

gives

```
===============================================
method         size 10    size 100    size 1000
------------------- untyped -------------------
bit-zerop-1    0.030 s     0.030 s      0.058 s
bit-zerop-2    0.112 s     1.000 s      9.324 s
bit-zerop-3    0.111 s     0.935 s      8.742 s
bit-zerop-4    0.047 s     0.047 s      0.063 s
-------------------- typed --------------------
bit-zerop-1    0.025 s     0.023 s      0.040 s
bit-zerop-2    0.036 s     0.315 s      3.005 s
bit-zerop-3    0.041 s     0.348 s      3.346 s
bit-zerop-4    0.010 s     0.012 s      0.026 s
===============================================
```

Comment: (every #'zerop #*000)

Comment: @coredump, thanks. That does answer my initial question, I guess, as I've asked for the idiomatic way :) It is still quite slow though. I've added the timings and changed the emphasis of the question to whether there is an efficient way.

Comment: Sorry I quickly wrote a comment because I had not much time at the moment, but I see now that you have a good answer.

Comment: If you want the fastest method you should mention the implementation you are using and add appropriate `DECLARE` forms to tell the compiler that the arguments are bitvectors (and that you want your function to be optimised).

Comment: @DanRobertson, fair point. I would expect the relative performance of the proposed answers to be the same whether typed or untyped, but who knows... I've added times with type declarations.

Comment: I’m pretty surprised at how well the first example works. I’d have expected the allocation to make it more expensive

Comment: @DanRobertson, I am surprised also, but I have just discovered that, in order to set all bits of a bit-vector to zero, allocating to a fresh new array populated with 0 by `(setf bit-vector (make-array size :element-type 'bit :initial-element 0))` is **60** (!) times quicker that setting successive bits to 0 by `(loop for i from 0 below size do (setf (sbit bit-vector i) 0))` (SBCL on typical laptop). It is probably linked to a very efficient way to create bit-vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an option:

```
(defun bit-vector-zerop (bit-vector)
  (not (find 1 bit-vector)))
```

This does not cons and is very efficient on SBCL. It's faster if you can declare the argument to be a bit-vector.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is any special bit logic function, see e.g. [here](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_bt_and.htm).

But how about this?

```
(loop
  for bit across #*0000
  never (= bit 1))
```